# Is there a way to show specific values from parameters like docking in an usercontrol?

Tags: c#

I'm building a usercontrol with visual studio 2017.

My control has a parameter that use docking to enhance visibility.

Here what I use :

```
public DockStyle OrganiserEmplacement {
        get
        {
            return _OrganiserEmplacement;
        }   
        set
        {
            _OrganiserEmplacement = value;
            Organiser.Dock = value;
        }
    }

private DockStyle _OrganiserEmplacement;
```

Is there a way in the editor that the DockStyle only show Left, Fill and Right values? I may use an enum, but it would be more userfriendly to use the DockStyle itself.

In fact, is there a way to hide specific parameters from the editor?

Comment: Make the enum type something else and not `DockStyle` and put the options you want in your enumeration type. There is no point in having the private field either.

Comment: I had trouble using the parameter directly, i may try harder